# How can I rewrite the path in a reverse proxy with Angular-CLI?

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

I have set up the reverse proxy with the angular2 CLI like the following:

```
{
  "/api/customer/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:9010",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

My problem is that the remote API is exposing a service on the path /customer, but the request that is sent by the reverse proxy is on /api/customer.

Is there a way to remove the /api from the request that is sent by the reverse proxy? (Don't answer with "just remove the /api from your http request", because I have an angular route on /customer).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do this fairly easy, using the `pathRewrite` option like so:

```
proxy: {
    '/api/customer/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:9010',
        pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}
    }
}
```

You can also take a look at the [Updated Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) for further information.

Answer (score 4):

Got this working using the same config as alex's answer. However, its essential to make your actual API requests to the frontend web server and not to the backend server.

For example, my backend is running on port 2777 and my frontend is running on port 1777

```
module.exports = {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:2777',
    pathRewrite: {'^/api': ''},
    logLevel: 'debug'
  }
}
```

And the base URL for API requests in environment.ts is:

```
apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:1777/api'
```

And an actual request would look like:

```
login(userCredentials: UserCredentials): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/auth/login', userCredentials).pipe(
    tap((user: User) => { this.authUser = user })
  )
}
```

This is great because it avoids the needs for CORS policies on the backend server. Hope this helps someone. I always forget to point my HTTP requests to the frontend server when I do this setup which causes endless pain figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: Can you please help me in my questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288953/