# Angular - blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *'

Tags: angular, typescript, cors

Getting error when I try to connect to a REST service that is in another domain. I understand it can be resolved by adding CORS in java rest service. But can it be possible by changing something in Angular side?

```
Access to 'http://someurl/RestWeb/getPerson' XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *'
```

My Rest service: http://someurl/RestWeb/getPerson,  all my rest service urls are like: http://someurl/RestWeb/SOMETHING

And my Angular url: http://someotherurl

After searching different articles, I already tried changing `proxy.conf.json` and `package.json` . Below re my changes, still I am getting same.

proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/RestWeb": {
    "target": "http://someurl/",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true  // I tried with and without this. No luck
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

service:

```
  findAll(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<string[]>('http://someurl/RestWeb/getPerson');
  }
```

run using:

```
npm start
```

As temporary counter measure, now I am testing my application in chrome browser using

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Please [don't post solutions in the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question). Post it as a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead. I've edited it out per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289344/how-to-treat-an-old-question-which-had-an-answer-edited-into-it). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that webpack-dev-server's proxy misused.

`proxy.conf.json`

```json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://someurl.com/",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      // replace `/api` with empty string, because real api path isn't contain 
      // `/api` segment
      // eg: http://localhost:4200/api/getPerson => http://someurl.com/getPerson
      "/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

`person.service.ts`

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  async getPerson() {
    return (
      this.http
        // you shouldn't use `http://someurl.com/getPerson` url directly,
        .get('/api/getPerson')
        .toPromise()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the rest service url. I am still confused about the pathRewite. Can you please see my question again and help me

Answer (score 2):

In your proxy configuration file, you are setting up the proxy for your `http://localhost:4200/api*`. So, the proxy will not work for `/getPerson`